# Snowflake METADATA$FILENAME key word not working in snowsql (Unix cmd prompt) but working in snowflake UI

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

Snowflake code

**Working in UI**

copy into DWR_NA.GTR_STG.BASE_REF_CSV_STG (FILE_NM,ROW_NM,CSV_CONTENT,LOAD_STATUS) from (select METADATA$FILENAME as FILE_NM,METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER as ROW_NM,$1as CSV_CONTENT, 'P' as LOAD_STATUS FROM @DWR_NA.GTR_STG.INT_REF_CSV_UNIX_STG)

**Same command not working in Unix snowsql**

snowsql -c SF_DWR_connection -d $SFDB -q "copy into DWR_NA.GTR_STG.BASE_REF_CSV_STG (FILE_NM,ROW_NM,CSV_CONTENT,LOAD_STATUS) from (select METADATA$FILENAME as FILE_NM,METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER as ROW_NM,$1 as CSV_CONTENT, 'P' as LOAD_STATUS FROM @DWR_NA.GTR_STG.INT_REF_CSV_UNIX_STG);"

**Error Message** 
000904 (42000): SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 104
invalid identifier 'METADATA'

I tried the above sql with Internal and External stage, but is not working.

Please suggestion.

Comment: As a workaround, can you try `IDENTIFIER('METADATA$FILENAME')` in place of `METADATA$FILENAME`

Comment: As it's solved, can you mark the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's just about escaping $ characters in double quoted strings. You need write them as "\$" So please try this:

```
snowsql -c SF_DWR_connection -d $SFDB -q "copy into
 DWR_NA.GTR_STG.BASE_REF_CSV_STG 
(FILE_NM,ROW_NM, CSV_CONTENT,LOAD_STATUS) from 
(select METADATA\$FILENAME as FILE_NM, 
METADATA\$FILE_ROW_NUMBER as ROW_NM, \$1 as CSV_CONTENT, 
'P' as LOAD_STATUS FROM @DWR_NA.GTR_STG.INT_REF_CSV_UNIX_STG);"
```

Comment: I have changed my code as you suggested and It is working as expected.
Thanks @Gokhan. much appreciated.
I was applying escape only to $1 and thought  METADATA$FILENAME is key specific to SF and it won't get break in Unix shell